# Using DoctrineBehaviors translatable in Symfony 4?

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I'm trying to use the DoctrineBehaviors translatable extension in Symfony 4.Just setup a test following the [documentation](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors) example:

translatable entity:

```
<?php

     namespace App\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Model as ORMBehaviors;

   /**
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\FAQRepository")
     */
    class FAQ
    {
        use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translatable;

        /**
         * @ORM\Id()
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         */
        protected $id;

        /.**
         * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
         */
        protected $updatedAt;

        public function getId(): ?int
        {
            return $this->id;
        }

        public function getUpdatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
        {
            return $this->updatedAt;
        }

        public function setUpdatedAt(?\DateTimeInterface $updatedAt): self
        {
            $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

            return $this;
        }
    }
```

translation entity:

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Model as ORMBehaviors;

    /**
     * @ORM\Entity
     */
    class FAQTranslation
    {
        use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translation;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="text")
         */
        protected $question;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="text")
         */
        protected $answer;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
         */
        protected $category;


        public function getQuestion(): ?string
        {
            return $this->question;
        }

        public function setQuestion(string $question): self
        {
            $this->question = $question;

            return $this;
        }

        public function getAnswer(): ?string
        {
            return $this->answer;
        }

        public function setAnswer(string $answer): self
        {
            $this->answer = $answer;

            return $this;
        }


        public function getCategory(): ?int
        {
            return $this->category;
        }

        public function setCategory(?int $category): self
        {
            $this->category = $category;

            return $this;
        }
    }
```

Testing the translatable entity:

```
        /**
         * @Route("/test", name="test")
         */
        public function testfaq()
        {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $faq = new FAQ();
            $faq->translate('fr')->setQuestion('Quelle est la couleur ?');
            $faq->translate('en')->setQuestion('What is the color ?');
            $em->persist($faq);

            $faq->mergeNewTranslations();
            $em->flush();

            return $this->render('app/test.html.twig', [
            ]);
        }
```

A new ID is added in the **faq** table.
But nothing is persisted in the **faqtranslation** table.

Bundles.php :

```
    Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Bundle\DoctrineBehaviorsBundle::class => ['all' => true],
```

All the documentations I found seem to refer to Symfony 3 or even Symfony 2, is it possible to use DoctrineBehaviors translatable in Symfony 4 ?

Comment: Maybe it has to do with $em->persist($faq); you are only persisting it to new FAQ(); ?

Comment: Yes according to the [documentation](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors) "The default naming convention (or its customization via trait methods) avoids you to manually handle entity associations. It is handled automatically by the TranslationSubscriber."

Comment: There is no recipe for the bundle, it's probably not supported in SF4. Not sure how to configure the bundle.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you found your answer since (I hope you did), but yes you can use KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors with Symfony 4. Maybe, you just needed to wait a little longer for an update.